# Como fazer para adicionar uma imagem de fundo com Jframe

Tags: java, jframe, intellij-idea, game

CLASS FASE

```
package meujogo.Modelo;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Fase{
    private Image fundo;

    public Fase(){
        String caminhoFundo = "src/resources/fundo.png";
        ImageIcon referencia = new ImageIcon(caminhoFundo);
        fundo = referencia.getImage();
    }


    public void paint(Graphics2D g){

        Graphics2D graficos = (Graphics2D) g;
        graficos.drawImage(fundo, 0, 0, null);
        g.dispose();
    }
```

CLASS CONTAINER

```
package meujogo;

import meujogo.Modelo.Fase;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Container extends JFrame {

    final int WIDHT = 1920;
    final int HEIGHT = 1080;

    private Graphics2D g;


    public Container() {

        add(new Fase());

        setSize(WIDHT, HEIGHT);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setUndecorated(true);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    private void add(Fase fase) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        new Container();
    }
}
```

A class container é onde está a Jframe, janela principal.
A class fase é a primeira fase do jogo.

Dentro da class fase estou tentando carregar uma imagem de fundo para aparacer na Janela principal.

A aplicação está iniciando porém o fundo não está carregando.
O intellij Iead não está informando nenhu erro

Poderiam me ajduar?

Comment: Esta pergunta [já foi postada](/q/593378/70) e lá já foram postadas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original, se restaurada).